# Monitor data from desktop to internet

Tags: security, desktop, privacy

I have few apps (driver detective) which communicate with there site from  desktop app. I need to check all data (URLs) for security reasons so that I am sure they are not accessing any private data. How can I monitor all such data.

I need to read all data being exchanged from my system to there server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Fiddler or Wireshark

Comment: Will Fiddler show network activity initiated by a desktop app?  It's not necessarily http traffic.

Comment: @EricJ.: That's why I said or Wireshark.

Comment: To be clear... they are not equivalent options (or am I missing something?)  If you look with Fiddler, you still have to look with Wireshark.  The app could call home via http, which Fiddler would see, and also call home using a different TCP protocol which Fiddler would not see.  So, checking with Fiddler does not guarantee that PII isn't being shipped home?

Comment: They both are really helpful. Digging in for more details but surprisingly desktop app cant connect to internet after installing Fiddler

Comment: I cant use them. Have to quit Fiddler to make that app run else it cant connect to internet . ANY IDEA ????????

Comment: @ITGuru Look at the app's proxy config, or just use Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor all network activity with a monitor such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

I suggest you invest some time learning how to setup filters with Wireshark before beginning.  There's a bit of a learning curve, but it will prevent you from becoming overwhelmed by the data passing over the wire.